# Converting a .png image RGB encoding 3-dim array into a matrix in R

Tags: r, image, matlab

If you have a `128x128` color image with the RGB encoding in an array of essentially three `128` matrices: one for the red colors; a second matrix for greens; and the third for blues, and you want to turn this array into a `16384x3` matrix in R to manipulate and compress the image, how can you do it?

In Matlab / Octave it would work out as:

```
img_size = size(image);
X = reshape(image, img_size(1) * img_size(2), 3);
```

Comment: You could try changing the `dim` attribute as appropriate; e.g. `ar = array(1:27, c(3, 3, 3)); ar; dim(ar) = c(prod(dim(ar)[1:2]), dim(ar)[3]); ar`

Comment: That is great, but could it be "merged" reading the values along the rows of the original matrices, as opposed to columnwise?

Comment: R stores matrices column-wise and that's why this happens. You could try `apply(ar, 3, t)` to simulate row-wise. Note, though, that `t`ransposing large arrays might not be memory efficient; perhaps, you might try changing your manipulations to work on a column-wise reshaped array if feasible

Comment: @alexis_laz So long as I have your attention... Would there be an easy way to turn `apply(ar, 3, t)` *back* into the original `ar`?

Comment: Having began like this, the most straightforward way would be to reverse the previous operation -- i.e. starting with the object from `apply(ar, 3, t)`, set its `dim` to `dim(ar)`, then `apply(, 3, t)` and set the `dim` of the resulting object to `dim(ar)`. Depending on what you're trying to do, though, you might consider using something like `for(i in 1:dim(ar)[3]) ar[, , i] = myFunction(ar[, , i])` to reduce drastically the amount of memory and time needed. Or perhaps, search for packages that might offer the functionality you need.

Comment: @alexis_laz How do you "set its `dim` to `dim(ar)`", and what would be the first argument of `apply(,3,t)`?

Comment: I tried to describe: `mat = apply(ar, 3, t); dim(mat) = dim(ar); mat2 = apply(mat, 3, t); dim(mat2) = dim(ar); mat2` :-)

Comment: @alexis_laz This is perfect! Why don't you write it up as an answer?

Comment: May I ask why in first place you want to combine individual color channels? Most image processing in R can be easily done on multi-dimensional arrays without the need of the suggested conversion, see e.g. the [examples in the documentation](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) of package [EBImage](http://bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage).

Comment: @EBImage I was trying to reproduce in R an exercise to compress a .png image using k-means. [Here is my code](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/k%20means%20image%20compression), and [this is the image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwl-HpVJ_5PeVHVpcnozQWt4ZEk). Regardless of the purely didactic purpose, I'd be interested in feedback regarding the matrix to image conversion at the end.